# Loop JSON data into ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am a newbie to ReactJS and was trying to fetch the data from JSON file.
I have created 2 files one is **products.json** and **app.jsx**. I can get the result in **console.log()**

```
[{…}]
0
:
{title: "Product Title", img: "./p-1.jpg", des: "DES1", rs: 599}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

but it's rendering in view. I sometimes get undefined, or the data itself is not populating.

**here's my react code.**

```
import React from 'react';
import Request from 'superagent';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
    Container,
    Col,
    Row,
    Card
} from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Header />
                <Content />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Header starts 
class Header extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        //alert('Header');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                <h1>Header !! </h1>
            </header>

        );
    }
}
// Header ends 

// Content starts 
class Content extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var url = "./products.json";
        Request.get(url)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.body.data);
                console.log(res.body.data.title);
                //this.setState({data: data.conversations});
                this.setState({
                    PTitle: res.body.title,
                    PImg: res.body.img,
                    PDesc: res.body.des,
                    PRs: res.body.rs
                });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                alert(err);
                // err.message, err.response
            });

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.data.map((key, i) => 
                    <ProductList key={i} products={key} />)
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
// Content ends 

// Footer starts 
class Footer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Footer !!
            </div>
        )
    }
}
// Footer ends


// Products Starts
class ProductList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            2. - <li>{PTitle}</li>
        )
    }
}
// Products Ends

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't see you updating `this.state.data` anywhere? Am I missing it?

Comment: nope., where i have to update ?

Comment: Aha -- I just noticed you have that line commented out: `this.setState({data: data.conversations});`. Is that intentional?

Comment: by commenting that it throws error "data is not defined "

Comment: Ah, sorry -- you probably want to update it to `res.body.data.conversations`.

Comment: :-( : new error - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: I see -- I'm not personally familiar with `superagent` so that's probably where the disconnect is. Try to `console.dir(res.body)` to see what you have available in the fetched JSON file. I'm guessing `superagent` doesn't actually parse the JSON, so you might need to drop a `JSON.parse(res.body.data)` somewhere in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163374/discussion-between-syed-azam-and-jonny-asmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `superagent` but It look like your input `./products.json` that serve as `http://localhost:3000/products.json` (assume you run react at port 3000)

I think first step you can replace serve static json to use mock server like https://www.mocky.io/ and generate response

but If you can serve static json with superagent you have to receive your data and then set to your component state.

If your request is success, set state,

```
// componentDidMount()

let url = 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a6032db100000fa02307802';

Request.get(url)
  .then((res) => {
    this.setState({data: res.body.data});  
  }).catch(() => {});
```

and update your `render()` method

```
return (
  <ul>
    {
      this.state.data.map((product, index) => (
        <ProductList key={index} product={product} />
      ))
    }
  </ul>
)
```

and the last, your `ProductList` in `render()` method because you send `product` as a props

```
render() {
  const { title, img, des, rd } = this.props.product;

  return (
    <li>{title} : {des} : {rd} : {img}</li>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. my missing part was setting const variables while printing.

Comment: {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Jackets",
            "img": "./img/p1.jpg",
            "rs": 9000,
            "buy": "Add to Cart",
            "details": "View Details",
            "detailPage": [
                {
                    "productDetail": "Made of Pure Leather",
                    "qty": 4,
                    "size" : 36
                }
            ]
        }
}
 i
how do i call detailPage [] and objects in render ?

Comment: If your `this.state.data` is your response above, then you can call `detailPage` (Array) with `map()` like your `this.state.data.map()` :  `detailPage.map(data => <p>{data.productDetail}</p>)`

Comment: componentWillMount() {
        let url = "./products.json";
        Request.get(url)
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.body.data
                });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                alert(err);
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <ul>
                    {
                        this.data.detailPage.map(data => <p>{data.productDetail}</p>)
                    }
                </ul>
            </Container>
        )
    }

Comment: Printing This gives me a error > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'detailPage' of undefined

Comment: @SyedAzam I think `this.data` is not correct, you should call `this.state.data` since `this.state.data` is array you have to loop and then call `detailPage` inside a loop or if you want to specific index like this 
`<Container> <ul> { this.state.data[0].detailPage.map(data => <p>{data.productDetail}</p>) } </ul> </Container> )` .

Comment: bro can you pl. have a look at this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498805/fetch-json-data-with-reactjs

Comment: hi, did you got the chance to look ? pl. let me know thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `superagent` uses `text` rather than `body` as one might expect. So what you'll need to do is parse your json file like this:

```
Request.get(url).then((res: any) =>{
    const json = JSON.parse(res.text);
    // If you have a conversations item in that response you can then do this
    this.setState({data: json.conversations});
    ...
```

Assuming that the value of `conversations` is an `Array`, you will have no problem then using `this.state.data.map` to iterate/loop over the values.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
What you need is

```
this.setState({data: res.body.data});
```

Then

```
this.state.data.map((one_product,i) => (
   <Product key={i} product={one_product}/>
);
```

and

```
class Product extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li>{this.props.product.title}</li>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: does your Request return an array of info for multiple products?

Comment: yes. [{…}] 0 : {title: "Product Title", img: "./p-1.jpg", des: "DES1", rs: 599} length : 1 proto : Array(0)

Comment: Edited, try it out

Comment: if its a nested how do i do it ? 

{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "detailPage": [
                {
                    "productDetail": "Made of Pure Leather"
               }
}
]

Answer (score 0):

Do setState for data array after the res in Ajax call. You are 
already doing that but commented. Try the below it has slight change

```
this.setState({
    data: res.body (or) res.body.data
})
```