# Redirect to Product Detail Page from Product List through JSON Data with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux

I'am able to get the first level of JSON Data i.e., objects / Product List

What I'am trying to achieve is on click of view button it has to open respective product detail page just like e-commerce website.

I have got stuck on the logic how i will bind and redirect to respective product page.

Now what I'am trying is :

i have created a new file ProductDetail.jsx and Lost what to do :-(

Appreciate your kind help!

File : products.json

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Jackets",
      "img": "./img/p1.jpg",
      "des": "Pure Leather Jacket",
      "rs": 9000,
      "buy": "Add to Cart",
      "details": "View Details",
      "detailPage": [
        {
          "productDetail": "Made of Pure Leather",
          "qty": 4,
          "size": "S, M, L, XL, XXL",
          "color":"white, black",
          "AddtoCart" : "Add to Cart"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

File : Products.jsx

```
/* Product List Starts */
export default class Products extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12} className="text-center">
                        <h2>MEN'S STYLES</h2>
                        <p>To Make a Lasting Impression</p>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <ProductsC />
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

// Products Component starts 
class ProductsC extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        let url = "./products.json";
        Request.get(url)
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.body.data
                });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                alert(err);
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <Row className="products-container">
                <Col sm={12}>
                    {
                        this.state.data.map(
                            (product, index) => (
                                <ProductList key={index} product={product} />
                            )
                        )
                    }
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}
// Products Component ends 

// Products Starts
class ProductList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { title, img, des, rs, buy, details } = this.props.product;
        return (
            <Col xs={12} sm={3} className="text-center product-list">
                <Card>
                    <CardImg src={img} alt="product img" />
                    <Link to="/">
                        <CardTitle>{title}</CardTitle>
                    </Link>
                    <CardText>{des}</CardText>
                    <CardText>Rs : {rs} /-</CardText>
                    <Button className='btn btn-danger'>{buy}</Button> &nbsp;
                    <Button className='btn btn-primary'>{details}</Button>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        )
    }
}
// Products Ends
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: going by the photo, everything looks like it should?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : Yeah Product is listing fine, but now when i click on each product it has to take me to Product Detail Page. which has to loop from nested json (data > "detailPage": [])

Comment: then pass across the `detailPage` part of your data

Comment: @mast3rd3mon : here is where i have got stuck :-( need help how to pass it

Comment: either pass it when you navigate or use a service file

Answer (score 1):

Your `Products` component could render to:

```
<Grid>
    <Row>
        <Col sm={12} className="text-center">
            <h2>MEN'S STYLES</h2>
            <p>To Make a Lasting Impression</p>
        </Col>
    </Row>
    <Route path="/products" exact component={ ProductsC } />
    <Route path="/products/:id" component={ ProductDetail } />
</Grid>
```

The first Route will render the `ProductsC` component that displays the list and a Link to "/products" + productID for each product. When navigating to that path, the second Route would be rendered, and the `ProductDetail` could get and show the detail of the product (the ID being `match.params.id`).

Comment: now it is redirecting to "http://localhost:2222/#/Products/1" only the url is changing  how do i match the id ?

Comment: In my example, "/products/:id" is not capitialized. Route matching is case sensitive. If the current path does not match, the Route will not render its component.

Answer (score 0):

To show `detailPage` you would need a separate route/page, then you could pass `detailPage` data to the page component.

Use a link instead of a button, it looks the same with class btn btn-default

```
 <Link to={`/Products/${ this.props.product.id }`}   className="btn btn-primary">
          View Details
  </Link>
```

You must have a route configured for `/Products/:id` ...

Comment: i have created a new file productDetail.jsx, Pl. help me write the logic init

Comment: make a call for "./products.json" & get the requried product by id, filter the array to get the product matching the id passed to it.  

use the `this.props.params.id` the id of product on which 'view details' has been clicked

Comment: what im doing is <Link to={`/productDetail/${this.props.product.id}`} className="btn btn-primary">
                        {details}
                    </Link>, Im redirecting to new page page productDetail+id

products.json iam making a call to it.

Comment: when you redirect to product detail page, from View Details what do you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164084/discussion-between-syed-azam-and-danish).